# Is possible to play Polarity cooperative campaign online?

Tags: polarity

I recently bought Polarity on sale, and already managed to complete both single player campaign and all the bonus levels.

I wanted to play also the cooperative campaign but the game seems to only have local multiplayer.

The thing is, the store page for the game on steam says "Single player", "Local Coop" and "Multiplayer".

Maybe i'm missing something? Is there a way to play the cooperative campaign over the internet?

Comment: If it doesn't have network multiplayer, you might be able to achieve a somewhat reasonable equivalent by using a tunneling service like Hamachi to connect you and a specific friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the steam store page does say `multi-player` and `local co-op`, the game is only local co-op. The game description and the gameplay video on the store page both say local co-op rather than multi-player. This could be because of a misunderstanding by the developer, as multi-player can be either online or offline.